# Multiple database connection node.js

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I need to use a different database for users.
Information about database name is stored in the user profile.

How can i make a database connection using a profile information?
In my model a use this code.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db2 = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/testdb' );
var Order = db2.model('Order');

exports.show = function(req, res, next){
    Order.find(function(err, order){
        if(err) return next(err);
        res.render('order/index',{
            orders: orders,


        });
    });
}
```

Comment: The 'createConnection' parameter is just a string.  Don't let users send the db name without making sure it's a datebase they are allowed to view.

Comment: Yes, I know. This information is not available for editing by the user

Comment: Its not clear where you access the profile info to get the connection string. I'd imagine you have access to it from a header value or cookie. I'd recommend that you look at building a piece of express middleware that passes the proper connection on the req object. Also, I'd think about a caching strategy for open connections. You will also need to move your model instance into your exported functions.